# Comment dire "as much as" en français ?

Tags: traduction

Je me demande comment dire "as much as" en français.
Par exemple, je voulais dire :

> As much as we try to stand out, we follow the same rules.

Ce que je propose :

> Autant qu’on essaye de se démarquer, on suit les mêmes règles.

Qu'en dites-vous ?

Comment: Pas le sujet de la question, mais on dira alors *on suit* (on utilise l'indicatif, pas de raison d'utiliser le subjonctif).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La traduction littérale proposée ne rend pas le sens d'opposition de *as much as* tel qu'utilisé ici.

Voici des traductions plus correctes:

> Bien qu'on essaie de se démarquer, on suit les mêmes règles

> On a beau essayer de se démarquer, on suit les mêmes règles

*Autant que* introduisant une subordonnée peut être utilisé, mais ce sera lors pour une comparaison de quantité:

> Il a mangé autant qu'il pouvait.

Comment: *Autant* on essaye de se démarquer, *autant* on suit les mêmes règles.

Answer (score 0):

(Non locuteur natif.)

DeepL propose :

> Autant nous essayons de nous démarquer, autant nous suivons les mêmes règles.

(vraiment un bon traducteur en ligne), ce qui est une version plus formel de la phrase de @Personne (voir commentaire dans la réponse de @Greg).

> Autant on essaye de se démarquer, autant on suit les mêmes règles.